# Using field values in a Word template

Tags: ms-word

I am building a template for documents that will be more pages long. I am using 'Rich text' and 'text' content control fields. I want the text of one of these content control field to appear in the footer of the document. I tried to use a StyleRef field in the footer and display the text having a specific style, the one in the field I want to show, but it does not work. It seems that Word is not looking inside those fields for the style (or sees a different style associated with that field ?).

How else can I achive this ?

Thank you !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to do this by selecting the whole content control using the side tab of the control and inserting a new Bookmark (via Insert Bookmark) and then inserting a ref field in the footer using the aforementioned bookmark name.

Comment: Thanks ! This almost works. There are two things that bother me now. The field does not get automatically updated, only on print or print preview. I could live with that. But the formatting of the text is not working. I want to have a different formatting in the footer field thatn the original field. And no matter if I change the font (face, color, etc.) in the footer field or if I unmark the 'preserve formatting during updates' option, it keeps copying the original formatting. Sometimes not for all the words in the field.

Comment: Press Alt-F9 to show field codes, then before the closing } of the field put "\\* MERGEFORMAT \\* CHARFORMAT" (no quotes) like {ref MyField \\* MERGEFORMAT \\* CHARFORMAT} then format your field and it should stick.   You may have to put some dummy text that is the maximum length you'll be using in the source field before you make your format changes to the footer (then you can change it back to blank or whatever after you've done your formatting)